# Stop WhatIf inheritance in cmdlets which don't use SupportsShouldProcess

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, powershell-5.1

What is the correct way to stop `WhatIfPreference` from being inherited by a child function?

I've written some functions for which it makes sense to use the `WhatIf` parameter to allow them to be run in safe/test mode.  However, these functions make calls to other cmdlets (e.g. writing logging into to a file) which I want to run regardless of the `WhatIf` parameter.  I'd assumed that `WhatIfPreference` would be automatically inherited by commands which have `SupportsShouldProcess` implemented (which is the case), but that any commands which didn't have this attribute wouldn't be aware of `SupportsShouldProcess`/`WhatIfPreference`, so would break the chain.

I could have those cmdlets that I want to always run call any cmdlets which implement `SupportsShouldProcess` with `-WhatIf:$False`; but that means putting this value in a lot of places and seems wrong given the calling context isn't aware of `SupportsShouldProcess`.

I could implement `SupportsShouldProcess` on all my cmdlets, then call those which I want to always run with `-WhatIf:$False` from those where I genuinely want to use `SupportsShouldProcess`; but again it feels silly to implement something just to not use it.

I'm certain there's a better option out there; but I've so far not found it.

### Example of this inheritance:

```
Function Nest1 {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    Param ()
    "Nest1 $WhatIfPreference"
    Nest2
}

Function Nest2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param ()
    "Nest2 $WhatIfPreference"
    Nest3
    Nest3 -WhatIf:$false
}

Function Nest3 {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    Param ()
    "Nest3 $WhatIfPreference"
}
```

Calling these functions with and without the -WhatIf parameter would produce the below behaviour:

```
Nest1
# Output:
#  Nest1 False
#  Nest2 False
#  Nest3 False
#  Nest3 False

Nest1 -WhatIf
# Output:
#  Nest1 True
#  Nest2 True
#  Nest3 True
#  Nest3 False
```

What I'd like to get is something like this:

```
Nest1 -WhatIf
# Output:
#  Nest1 True
#  Nest2 False     # as it doesn't implement SupportsShouldProcess
#  Nest3 False     # as its caller doesn't implement SupportsShouldProcess
#  Nest3 False     # multiple reasons (caller and -WhatIf:$False)
```

Comment: [`$WhatIfPreference` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7#whatifpreference) is always present, defaults to `$false` and (like other variables) doesn't change spontaneously. (in given scope). The [`SupportsShouldProcess` argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7#supportsshouldprocess)  (or its absence) does not change the `$WhatIfPreference`'s value…

Comment: On the other hand, the `$WhatIfPreference` variable keeps its value in given scope until changed (indifferently if changed explicitly either by an assignment statement, or by using `-WhatIf` in  a caller  that supports it)…

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ; that makes sense; I'd just hoped that when `SupportsShouldProcess` wasn't implemented, the value would be set back to false within that function's scope (and thus by default the scope of any child processes); or at least that there would be a way to easily cause that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to set `$WhatIfPreference = $false` as the first line of any cmdlets which don't implement `SupportsShouldProcess` so that they won't pass this value down to any cmdlets which they call, even when those cmdlets implement `SupportsShouldProcess`.  It feels hacky, but is cleaner than the other options.  Due to variable scopes, thankfully changes to this variable do not impact the caller; so in the example below both Nest1 outputs show this value as being true, even though the second one's after the Nest2 call.

```
Function Nest1 {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    Param ()
    "Nest1 $WhatIfPreference"
    Nest2
    "Nest1 $WhatIfPreference"
}

Function Nest2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param ()
    $WhatIfPreference = $false
    "Nest2 $WhatIfPreference"
    Nest3
}

Function Nest3 {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    Param ()
    "Nest3 $WhatIfPreference"
}
```